# In react is there any way to wait for child components state and re-render the parent along with child component

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class AddSpinner extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        //API call to thunk and a state gets updates in redux
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <div>
                    {/* jsx values */}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {/* call another component basically a child component */}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So here in the render, there are few jsx and then the call to child component is happening where there is another API call in componentDidMount.
My question is how do I wait for the child components API call to complete and return the state to parent and meanwhile not render the jsx that is called before the child component and show a spinner meanwhile.

Comment: You already using redux, use an action which indicates when the loading stops

Comment: Yes, I am using action which indicates success. The problem here is checking both the API's success in the parent component before the render and the child component call is within the parent's render.

Comment: I dont understand the problem, on success update the state, when both api succeed and the child render, remove the loading

Comment: The problem here is during the parent render there are few jsx elements and within that jsx elements there is the call for child component. so how do I put the condition before that jsx to not render the jsx of both parent and child and also call the child componentDidMount and update the state? Once both the states are updated then render both the components.

Comment: please make a producible example of such case